# Can't retrieve file meta data from Google Drive, 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-drive-api

I'm having some seriously weird issues with the Google Drive API.

Bear with me here, there's a lot to explain.

I originally got the API working using one of my Google accounts -- let's call it `test@google.com` for simplicity. I got the Google Picker UI working and it correctly displays the list of files in my Drive account.

I set it to my APP_ID and I have some server-side logic that uses the official `google-ruby-api-client` gem to connect to the Drive API using the `drive.files.get` endpoint. I can then download the file's metadata using this snippet:

```
require 'google/api_client'

client = Google::APIClient.new

# client ID and secret from Google APIs Console
client.authorization.client_id = "{CLIENT_ID}"
client.authorization.client_secret = "{SECRET}"
client.authorization.redirect_uri = "http://myapp.com/users/auth/gdrive"
# access token stored in database from oauth2 flow
client.authorization.access_token = "TOKEN"

client.authorization.scope = [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
]
result = client.execute!(
  :api_method => 'drive.files.get',
  :version => 'v2',
  :parameters => { 'fileId' => params[:file_id] })
```

With the `test@google.com` account I tried this on, the result comes back with the file's metadata, and I'm able to download the file. All peachy.

The problem comes when I use a *different* Google account. I can access the files in Picker, but when the request is sent to the server with the `fileId` using the above, I just keep getting a 404 error, saying that the file doesn't exist. I've also tried to access the file's metadata using the OAuth 2.0 Playground provided by google, but the weird thing is that I still get that error, but I also get the same 404 error when I use the `test@google.com` account.

The only thing I can really think of is that I submitted a version of my app with all the Google Drive details once, and installed the app via the Chrome Webstore. After I realized it was showing up for everyone as a Drive-enabled app, I promptly removed it and changed the manifest.json file back to its normal, non-Drive enabled state. I did read that you should have the app installed via the Chrome Webstore to work properly, but I also read that that's not the case anymore. Are your installed Chrome Webstore apps stored in Google's cloud somewhere so they know that it was installed for a particular account? Or are webstore apps just installed locally? I'm so confused.

What am I missing here? I haven't been this frustrated with an API in a really long time. Please help!

Comment: Is there any chance that your AppId is tied to your user account in some specific way? Do you need to pass some hurdles before it works "for everyone"?

Comment: I don't think so -- not from what I can glean from the Google APIs console anyway. There are two developers under the Team section, and only my account can be accessed.

Comment: Could you be perhaps using the wrong account for the picker API? If you are multiply logged in with the same browser this could happen.

Comment: @AliAfshar, no -- I'm explicitly setting the account with the user's ID from the `userInfo` API. The images that come up are from the correct account. Does the Chrome Webstore app have to be installed for it to work?

Comment: No, webstore is not required for the picker. This is strange indeed. Could you try using the full scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive temporarily to see if the issue is related to the file-only scope?

Comment: @AliAfshar -- just tried changing the scope to the full drive API. I still get the same error: `Google::APIClient::ClientError (File not found: 0B1616ziJl8P4TEtEak1KZko0ZTQ):`. The interesting thing is that when I use the picker I get these two values in the `pickerCallback` response when I choose a file: `{ driveError: "PERMISSION_DENIED",
driveSuccess: false }`. I also get this error when I use the `test@google.com` account as stated above, but the `file.get` still works.

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon, I made a mistake. I hadn't switched the scope to the full scope, I was missing one somewhere. I just tried the full scope like you said, and it worked! That's curious though -- why would it do that?

Comment: So, it is a bit too complex to describe here in a comment, but when the user selects a file in the picker, Google Drive adds that file to the list of files that an application can access with the drive.file scope. Clearly somewhere in that step the file isn't getting added. This might be because of the web store, but there might be another cause which I will investigate after the weekend. For now, if the full scope works, please use it.

Comment: Thank you @AliAfshar! Can you please post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Ali Afshar for the answer -- the solution (for now) is to temporarily use the full scope of Google Drive instead of just the `drive.file` scope.

e.g. instead of using this scope,

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
```

use this one instead:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
```

Comment: Wow this one was pretty hard to pin down! Thank you @calvin-l for the tip. In my case, I wasn't able to convert a Google Document (which someone else create but gave me access to) into PDF, even though I was able to retrieve its metadata. Changing the scope to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` made the whole thing work.