# Change the scope, and the files gone

Tags: google-drive-api

my application had worked with the scope  /auth/drive  a long time,  the users  have uploaded files with this scope and now if I change the scope to auth/drive.file cannot listing the files uploaded. The app works perfect but the old files gone.

Can I make something for this? Change some file properties , or import files to aplication.

Thanks

Comment: I think that in your question, these threads might be the answers. https://stackoverflow.com/q/11354779 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/15993268

Comment: What exactly is failing? Can you post your code?